# Visual Basic loading form object with database table values

Tags: database, vb.net

I'm currently wrapping up my VB final project which was creating a 4x4 sudoku puzzle with a button called "Check Solution". When the users enters an incorrect solution, a message box pops up and tells them where the error is, if and when they enter a correct solution, it stores the single line of input into access table. Now I have a "Generate" button that reads the single line of input from the access table into the combo boxes. Basically it shows them the last correct solution entered. I'm unsure how to accomplish the code for pulling the single row of values from the DB and into the form. THanks ahead of time.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking? Are you serializing the solution and wanting to load it back in the puzzle?

Comment: Basically...like when they enter a correct solution, it updates the FIRST and ONLY row in the access table...which i've done. But when they hit the generate button I want to pull those values and place them back into the puzzle.

Comment: so like, even if it's a new game with blank values, if they hit generate, it fills in a correct solution

Comment: I know I would use a "SELECT * FROM Solutions" but I'm unsure of the syntax for the rest of the code. I've done something extremely similar in java but I'm drawing a blank

Comment: try this article for the syntax  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/select-statement-HA001231497.aspx